# How to check whether there is traffic on EoMPLS L2VPN circuit?

Tags: cisco, mpls, mpls-vpn

I'm trying to check which of the virtual circuits are up, down and admin down.
For example take this scenario.
[image]

Here I have 6 VCs up and 4 down.
I want to know what does it mean when it is down, should I consider it dead customer or terminated one?
Second how can I check if there is traffic on the up VCs.
[image]
Here is a VC that is up and now I know its port as well.

This is how output of Sh int Gi6/5.530 looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please, never use an image for text in your question. Simply copy the text and paste it into your question using the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`). Please correct this in your question.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the physical interfaces on the CE side and check byte counts.  Or you can configure Netflow on the routers to report traffic.